# Maven create project command

Tags: java, maven

I have run this two command,

1.>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.companyname.automobile -DartifactId=trucks -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false

2.>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.companyname.bank -DartifactId=consumerBanking -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

Both are creating two different folder structure.why??

Comment: Because of the different parameters?

Comment: well a web app would have a different structure to a normal java project wouldn't it. see http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Comment: I haven't got it .pls explain.

Comment: what don't you understand?  web app project vs normal java project?

Comment: oh i got it its because of two diffrerent parameter.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Archetype maven-archetype-webapp is used for web applications and has folder like webapp, and maven-archetype-quickstart is a simple java project.